Is it possible to change the zoom direction in the graph editor using Ctrl + Middle Mouse by moving the mouse to the right instead of to the left?
In the graph editor, we can zoom in and out using the Ctrl + Middle Mouse shortcut.
We zoom in vertically by moving the mouse down, and horizontally by moving the mouse to the left.
I would like to zoom horizontally by moving the mouse to the right instead of to the left.
Is it possible?
I searched in Blender preferences but found nothing about this.
